# SolrIndexer indexer failed nutch

Tags: solr, nutch

How to solve this error ?

Iam using `nutch 1.12`, `hadoop 2.7.2` and `solr 6.0.0` and have copyied nutch `schema.xml` file into Solr `conf` file and this my nutch log error

when I am running this command

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/#/devel1 crawl_Test1/crawldb -linkdb crawl_Test1/linkdb  crawl_Test1/segments/*
```

In this url you can see the error [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2271)

Answer (score 0):

Restart solr by again running the command "java -jar start.jar" and then try again to run the last command.